# Values is empty in $_REQEST['ID'] but it Exist in $_POST['ID']

Tags: php

When i try to print form value with POST it work fine

```
var_dump($_POST); // Value  is there
```

In next Line i try to dump $_REQUEST it's empty.

```
var_dump($_REQUEST) // Empty
```

I am not getting why its happening like this.

Comment: What values you are trying to access?

Comment: Did you set values to the `$_POST` var manually?

Comment: what version of php are you using

Comment: value is $_REQEST['ID']  ID,

Comment: @Ulver value is in hidden field(name="ID") of the form

Answer (score 0):

Check the http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order setting in your php.ini, should not be empty and probably be set to "GC" if you want GET and POST in that order.

In my php.ini (you can run php --ini from the terminal to find where your php.ini is):

```
; This directive determines which super global arrays are registered when PHP
; starts up. If the register_globals directive is enabled, it also determines
; what order variables are populated into the global space. G,P,C,E & S are
; abbreviations for the following respective super globals: GET, POST, COOKIE,
; ENV and SERVER. There is a performance penalty paid for the registration of
; these arrays and because ENV is not as commonly used as the others, ENV is
; is not recommended on productions servers. You can still get access to
; the environment variables through getenv() should you need to.
; Default Value: "EGPCS"
; Development Value: "GPCS"
; Production Value: "GPCS";
; http://php.net/variables-order
variables_order = "GPCS"
```